# nonlinear matrix input to MATLAB's fmincon: how to

Tags: matlab, matrix, mathematical-optimization

I have a myfun.m file that defines the following function:

```
f = 0.5 * (norm(C*x - d))^2;
```

and it is called in a main script by:

```
[x, fval] = fmincon(@myfun, x0, -A, b, Aeq, beq, lb, ub);
```

C is a 170x72 matrix, d is a 170x1 vector, so x is a 72x1 vector. This part works well.

Now I want to multiply each element of C by a constant raised to a power, and solve for that power. So instead of C(1,1) = 4, now it should be = (2^p)*4. However, I want p to be solved for in the optimization as well, so p = x(73). I realize that augmenting the x matrix means I have to update x0, A, b, Aeq, beq, lb, ub to all include 73 elements, which I've done. The problem arises when I define the elements of the C matrix like C(1,1)= (2^x(73))*4, I get the: 
"Index exceeds matrix dimensions" 
error every time I run the code.

The new x(73) element has no constraints or bounds associated with it (the lower and upper bounds are -inf and inf). Any thoughts on why this is not working or how to fix it? Is it somehow invalid to use an element of x inside C, then multiply by x as I do in the cost function?

Note: I realize this cost function looks just like least squares. I used fmincon originally since I had multiple objectives, and will continue to use it after I solve this problem because I need to add in nonlinear constraints.

UPDATE: I'm taking small steps through the error: first, I augmented the x0, A, Aeq, lb, ub, and C matrices/vectors to include the 73rd column, but don't actually use x(73) anywhere in C, and the corresponding elements in the above matrices/vectors that multiply x(73) are 0.  This actually works fine now, but when I print the x vector, it's only 72 elements long!  Not sure why this would be when all the other inputs are 73 now.  My thought is once I figure that out, I can try to use x(73) in the C matrix again.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the concept.  Probably a bug in your implementation.  Which we'd be happy to help with if you'd show it.

Comment: Debugging dimension-mismatch is usually not that hard.  Tell MATLAB to drop to the debugger on error (`dbstop if error`), then inspect the dimensions of every single variable and constant in the offending expression.

Comment: I would love to show the implementation but there are several large m files linked with global variables, etc. so it's not as easy as posting a snippet of code.  Thanks for the (dbstop if error) suggestion.  I just posted an update.